# Generated tests fail in Spring Cloud Contract

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-contract

I am new to spring-cloud-contract. Just trying to configure my build and I am getting error.

Here is my project structure

> Project
>      | ==> Module

I have the following dependencies for classpath in my project build.gradle

**Project Build file**

```
buildscript {
dependencies {
    classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.2.1"
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.4.RELEASE")
    classpath "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-gradle-plugin:1.1.3.RELEASE"
}
apply from: "$projectDir/gradle/app/springcloud.gradle" //Gradle build file in module
}
```

**Module Build file**

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'spring-cloud-contract'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
dependencies {
//Spring cloud contract dependencies
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
testCompile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier')
testCompile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner"
testCompile "com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured:2.5.0"
testCompile "com.jayway.restassured:spring-mock-mvc:2.5.0"
}
  //Spring cloud contract dependency management
dependencyManagement {
imports {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Dalston.RELEASE"
  }
}
```

I have a groovy file which has a post request and a response. When I do `gradle build`, the tests are autogenerated but my build is feeling.

```
C:\Users\user\Projects\myProject\module\build\generated-test-sources\contracts\org\springframework\cloud\contract\verifier\tests\ContractVerifierTest.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext;
                      ^
symbol:   class DocumentContext
location: package com.jayway.jsonpath

C:\Users\user\Projects\myProject\module\build\generated-test-sources\contracts\org\springframework\cloud\contract\verifier\tests\ContractVerifierTest.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
        DocumentContext parsedJson = 
JsonPath.parse(response.getBody().asString());
        ^
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any mismatch in the versions which I am using?

Comment: Most likely you have a version mismatch. Please check out this repo https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/producer/build.gradle with samples of spring cloud contract and update your project to look the same

Comment: I am applying spring cloud contract to existing project. Looks like the project has already got spring boot in its dependency. I will try looking into dependency tree to figure out the conflicts.

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak my project used `springBootversion=1.4.3.RELEASE`, can't change or upgrade it. Which `spring-cloud-contract-gradle-plugin` is compatable with this version? Also I am using `spring-cloud-dependencies:Camden.SR7` Does this it? Thanks for your help

Comment: AFAIR you can go only with Camden since Dalston requires Boot 1.5, but you can try. Also `testCompile "com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured:2.5.0"
testCompile "com.jayway.restassured:spring-mock-mvc:2.5.0"` this is unnecessary cause it comes with the verifier starter (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/blob/master/spring-cloud-contract-starters/spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier/pom.xml#L15-L39)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Marcin Thanks for your inputs. This is how I solved this issue.

The build fails inside generated tests and jayway jsonpath is not showing in Red colour at the position of error. When I Ctrl + Hover (mouse) on the import it's referencing to `com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.2.0` which is not true. The reason is because I have imported many modules in Intellij and apparently one of the module also imports `2.2.0` and intellij is referencing it from external library.

So I did invalidate cache intellij and closed all unnecessary projects and reopened the project alone which I am working on, in a new window (Fresh session). Now `gradle build` and again I got the same error on the generated tests. But this time When I Ctrl + Hover (mouse) on the import its refering to the `com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:0.9.1` which is what I am expecting.

Now to solve this issue, I've examined the dependency tree using the below command and did some `grep` on it.

`allDeps --configuration testRuntime`

I found the answer, why gradle is replacing `2.2.0` with `0.9.1`. I've figured out some project dependency is replacing it. Now the solution for this is modifying my module build file for jayway json-path as shown below. After that I've given `build gradle` command and now the errors are gone.

```
testCompile ('com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.2.0') {
            force = true
}
```

And finally, I've got exception saying that `SpringCloudContractAssertions` unable to find.

`org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.assertion.SpringCloudContractAssertions.assertThat;`

So I replace `Camden` release with `Dalston` as shown below. Now it all works fine.

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Dalston.RELEASE"
    }
}
```